# Mod_rewrite Rules for MVC Architecture

Tags: model-view-controller, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

In my site you can open pages like this...

```
example.com/?controller=index&action=index
```

I want to make links nicer so I use mod_rewrite...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$  index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It works perfectly and result is somehow like this...

```
example.com/index/index
```

But my problem is that this link, where is set only the 1st variable won't work. Don't know how to fix it! This won't work...

```
example.com/index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ index.php?mod=$1&act=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ index.php?mod=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, just if there is set just $c, like /foo. It will open /?c=index&a=index. But I want it to open /?c=foo&a=index then. =]